# How to send a value to smart contract function using meta mask and web3.js?

Tags: web3js, metamask, send

I tried to follow a tutorial https://livecodestream.dev/post/interacting-with-smart-contracts-from-web-apps/

I was able to retrieve the number via call function, but was not able to update the number via send function.
I don't use infura. I use MetaMask and it is connected to my page on local host. I gave permission to use the Meta Mask accounts.

I trigger the function by button

```
<button onclick="changeCoolNumber();">Change Cool Number</button>
```

My inpage Javascript is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
async function loadWeb3() {
      if (window.ethereum) {
          window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
          window.ethereum.enable();
      }
}

async function loadContract() {
    return await new window.web3.eth.Contract([
        {
            "inputs": [],
            "name": "coolNumber",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "stateMutability": "view",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "_coolNumber",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "setCoolNumber",
            "outputs": [],
            "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
            "type": "function"
        }
    ], '0x5F4a8C71AFB0c01BA741106d418E78888607Ee63');
}

async function getCurrentAccount() {
    const accounts = await window.web3.eth.getAccounts();
    return accounts[0];
}

async function printCoolNumber() {
    const num = await window.contract.methods.coolNumber().call();
    document.querySelector("output").textContent = num;
}

async function changeCoolNumber() {
    const value = parseInt(45);
    const account = await getCurrentAccount();
    console.log("accounts", account);
    const coolNumber = await window.contract.methods.setCoolNumber(value).send({ from: account });
}

async function load() {
    await loadWeb3();
    updateStatus('Web3 Ready!');
    window.contract = await loadContract(); 
    updateStatus('Contract Ready!');
    
}

load();
```

From all I heard so far is, that Meta Mask should pop up for signing the transaction to change the number via setCoolNumber(). I'm using Firefox with MetaMask extention. HTTP-Server as local server and the following web3.js

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@1.7.0/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```

I hope anybody can help me solve this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Finally MetaMask pops up with the following send() command. (There is a colon after the accountadress)

```
const coolNumber = await window.contract.methods.setCoolNumber(45).send({ from: '0xDe.....', });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Adding a default account helped me: `web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];`

Comment: Thank you Kostiantyn. Does a defaultAccount mean that I can use send() without a "from: account" statement? Could you share your code please?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to use it without "from: account". There is nothing special in my code that you wouldn't see in yours. Just remove the "from" part, and add the setting of defaultAccount in load function. Please tell me if that advice worked for you!

Comment: I pasted it as follows, but somehow I get the error: "Uncaught (in promise) Error: No "from" address specified in neither the given options, nor the default options"

Comment: `async function load() {
          await loadWeb3();
          window.contract = await loadContract();
         // window.web3.eth.defaultAccount = await getCurrentAccount();
          window.web3.eth.defaultAccount = window.web3.eth.accounts[0]; 
      }` Doesn't work.